# Validation does not work in bootstrap 3 modal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using some popover validation of modal in bootstrap 3, but form is submited using ajax, and validation works, but the ajax is executed beside validation?

Here is my code, when someone click submit, validation popup but ajax continues?

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Please edit customer data</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-error" style="display:none;"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>  <strong>Error!</strong> A problem has been occurred while submitting your data.</div>
            <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success" style="display:none;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read <a href="#" class="alert-link">this important alert message</a>.</div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" data-async="" action="http://plasticnestolice.com/customers/edit.html" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input name="username" data-placement="left" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 3 characters long" class="form-control required" placeholder="Email" autofocus="" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i> Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);
            var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
            $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function(data, status) {
                    $(".alert-success").toggle();
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function() {
                    $(".alert-error").toggle();
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.goValidate = function() {
            var $form = this,
                $inputs = $form.find('input:text, input:password'),
                $selects = $form.find('select'),
                $textAreas = $form.find('textarea');
            var validators = {
                name: {
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/
                },
                username: {
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]{6,}$/
                },
                firstName: {
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/
                },
                lastName: {
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/
                },
                town: {
                    regex: /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/
                },
                postcode: {
                    regex: /^.{3,}$/
                },
                password1: {
                    regex: /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/
                },
                password1_repeat: {
                    regex: /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/
                },
                email: {
                    regex: /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/
                },
                phone: {
                    regex: /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/,
                },
                body: {
                    regex: /^.{3,}$/
                },
                country: {
                    regex: /^(?=\s*\S).*$/,
                }
            };
            var validate = function(klass, value) {
                var isValid = true,
                    error = '';
                if (!value && /required/.test(klass)) {
                    error = 'This field is required';
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    klass = klass.split(/\s/);
                    $.each(klass, function(i, k) {
                        if (validators[k]) {
                            if (value && !validators[k].regex.test(value)) {
                                isValid = false;
                                error = validators[k].error;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return {
                    isValid: isValid,
                    error: error
                }
            };
            var showError = function($e) {
                var klass = $e.attr('class'),
                    value = $e.val(),
                    test = validate(klass, value);
                $e.removeClass('invalid');
                $('#form-error').addClass('hide');
                if (!test.isValid) {
                    $e.addClass('invalid');
                    if (typeof $e.data("shown") == "undefined" || $e.data("shown") == false) {
                        $e.popover('show');
                    }
                } else {
                    $e.popover('hide');
                }
            };
            $inputs.keyup(function() {
                showError($(this));
            });
            $selects.change(function() {
                showError($(this));
            });
            $textAreas.keyup(function() {
                showError($(this));
            });
            $inputs.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
                $(this).data("shown", true);
            });
            $inputs.on('hidden.bs.popover', function() {
                $(this).data("shown", false);
            });
            $form.submit(function(e) {
                $inputs.each(function() { /* test each input */
                    if ($(this).is('.required') || $(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
                        showError($(this));
                    }
                });
                $selects.each(function() { /* test each input */
                    if ($(this).is('.required') || $(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
                        showError($(this));
                    }
                });
                $textAreas.each(function() { /* test each input */
                    if ($(this).is('.required') || $(this).hasClass('invalid')) {
                        showError($(this));
                    }
                });
                if ($form.find('input.invalid').length) { /* form is not valid */
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#form-error').toggleClass('hide');
                }
            });
            return this;
        };
        $('form').goValidate();
    });
```

Here is working bootply, i dont know why validation does not stop ajax call??

http://www.bootply.com/J5QItCF3Ue

Comment: In which part of the code are you actually trying to stop the ajax call when there are validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `jQuery(function($) {}` is functional equal to `$(document).ready(function()`.

On submitting the form you trigger both the `$('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {}` and the `$form.submit(function(e) {}` actions.

rewrite `jQuery(function($) {
        $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) { });` to a global function:
var formsubmit = function(){};`

And than inside the `$('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {}` code:

```
if ($form.find('input.invalid').length) { /* form is not valid */
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#form-error').toggleClass('hide');
                }
else {
formsubmit();
e.preventDefault();
}
```